# Motor Speed Output Signal

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller, rpm

I need an advice.
I just got a DC motor and its controller board.

On the controller board it has 6 pin/wire: +12V, GND, PWM, ENABLE, DIRECTION, SPEED OUT.

What I want to know is how do I interpret the signal on SPEED OUT?

This signal supposed to be carrying information about the RPM speed the motor currently running right?

If so then to interpret it which one I should look, the duty cycle or the frequency of the signal?

How do I know the relation between the signal and the speed the motor currently running?

Do I need to find the relation by testing/calibrate it? (like using tool like digital tachometer?)

Comment: This is unanswerable without engineering details of your controller board.

Comment: This makes no sense. What are you not telling us?

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to just probe the signal if you have an oscilloscope. Spin the motor by hand. Even without an oscilloscope, you can very slowly spin the motor by hand and see if you get a signal by voltmeter. Controller should be powered on but not driving the motor. Make sure you don't get injured if the motor should begin spinning on its own while you are touching it (basically, be careful).

Comment: Most motor speed out sensors are a simple Tach output which are either V/ kRPM using a constant pulse width or Hz * 60= RPM for n=1 pole per rev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the details are thin but I'll take a stab at answering.

RPM or tachometer signals are frequently generated by Hall Effect sensors. The resulting signal will be a square wave whose *frequency* is proportional to the rotational velocity.  Some motors have a tach signal that generates more than one pulse per revolution.  You'll have to experiment to determine the number of pulses per revolution or read the data sheet if you have one.

A common way to measure the RPM is to connect the tach signal to a timer/counter in your microcontroller and count the time between similar edges. For lower RPM ranges another way is to use interrupts. For each tach pulse edge (rising to rising or falling to falling) generate an interrupt and note the value of a free-running counter. Do the math and voila, RPM.

You will frequently need a pullup resistor (10K or so to VCC) as the Hall Effect sensors will typically only drive low. Read the datasheet if you can find one.

Comment: "RPM or tachometer signals are nearly always generated by Hall Effect sensors" not really, traditionally they are generated by DC generators or winding having that purpose.  Further, this is allegedly an output from the *controller*, not the *motor*.

Comment: Agreed. Definitely not enough info provided to say definitively.